# Boost Asio and Udp Poll() No incoming data

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio, polling

**I have to handle information from 100 ports in parallel for 100ms per second.**

I am using Ubuntu OS.

I did some research and i saw that `poll()` function is a good candidate, to avoid to open 100 threads to handle in parallel data coming on udp protocol.

I did main part with boost and I tried to integrate poll() with boost.

**The problem is when i am trying to send by client data to the server, I receive nothing.
According to wireshark, data are coming on the right host. (localhost, port 1234)**

**Did I miss something or did I put something wrong ?**

[image]

**The test code (server)** :

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <sys/poll.h>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>


using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using namespace boost::asio;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::string ip_address = "127.0.0.1";

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t arraySize( T(&)[N] )
{
    return(N);
}

class UdpReceiver
{
    using Resolver   = udp::resolver;
    using Sockets    = std::deque<udp::socket>;
    using EndPoint   = udp::endpoint;
    using Buffer     = std::array<char, 100>; // receiver buffer

public:
    explicit UdpReceiver()
            : work_(std::ref(resolver_context)), thread_( [this]{ resolver_context.run(); })
    { }

    ~UdpReceiver()
    {
        work_ = boost::none; // using work to keep run active always !
        thread_.join();
    }

    void async_resolve(udp::resolver::query const& query_) {
        resolver_context.post([this, query_] { do_resolve(query_); });
    }

    // callback for event-loop in main thread
    void run_handler(int fd_idx) {
        // start reading
        auto result = read(fd_idx, receive_buf.data(), sizeof(Buffer));
        // increment number of received packets
        received_packets = received_packets + 1;
        std::cout << "Received bytes " << result << " current recorded packets " << received_packets <<'\n';

        // run handler posted from resolver threads
        handler_context.poll();
        handler_context.reset();
    }

    static void handle_receive(boost::system::error_code error, udp::resolver::iterator const& iterator) {
        std::cout << "handle_resolve:\n"
                     "  " << error.message() << "\n";
        if (!error)
            std::cout << "  " << iterator->endpoint() << "\n";
    }

    // get current file descriptor
    int fd(size_t idx)
    {
        return sockets[idx].native_handle();
    }

private:

    void do_resolve(boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::query const& query_) {

        boost::system::error_code error;
        Resolver resolver(resolver_context);
        Resolver::iterator result = resolver.resolve(query_, error);

        sockets.emplace_back(udp::socket(resolver_context, result->endpoint()));

        // post handler callback to service running in main thread
        resolver_context.post(boost::bind(&UdpReceiver::handle_receive, error, result));
    }

private:
    Sockets sockets;
    size_t received_packets = 0;
    EndPoint remote_receiver;
    Buffer receive_buf {};

    io_context resolver_context;
    io_context handler_context;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_context::work> work_;
    std::thread thread_;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    UdpReceiver udpReceiver;
    udpReceiver.async_resolve(udp::resolver::query(ip_address, std::to_string(1234)));

    //logic
    pollfd fds[2] { };
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize(fds); ++i)
    {
        fds[i].fd = udpReceiver.fd(0);
        fds[i].events = 0;
        fds[i].events |= POLLIN;
        fcntl(fds[i].fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    }

    // simple event-loop
    while (true) {
        if (poll(fds, arraySize(fds), -1)) // waiting for wakeup call. Timeout - inf
        {
            for(auto &fd : fds)
            {
                if(fd.revents & POLLIN) // checking if we have something to read
                {
                    fd.revents = 0; // reset kernel message
                    udpReceiver.run_handler(fd.fd); // call resolve handler. Do read !
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a confused mix of C style `poll` code and Asio code. The point is

- you don't need poll (Asio does it internally (or epoll/select/kqueue/IOCP - whatever is available)
- UDP is connectionless, so you don't need more than one socket to receive all "connections" (senders)

I'd replace it all with a single `udp::socket` on a single thread. You don't even have to manage the thread/work:

```
net::thread_pool io(1); // single threaded
udp::socket s{io, {{}, 1234}};
```

Let's run an asynchronous receive loop for 5s:

```
std::array<char, 100> receive_buffer;
udp::endpoint sender;

std::function<void(error_code, size_t)> read_loop;
read_loop = [&](error_code ec, size_t bytes) {
    if (bytes != size_t(-1)) {
        //std::cout << "read_loop (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
        if (ec)
            return;

        received_packets += 1;
        unique_senders.insert(sender);
        //std::cout << "Received:" << bytes << " sender:" << sender << " recorded:" << received_packets << "\n";
        //std::cout << std::string_view(receive_buffer.data(), bytes) << "\n";
    }
    s.async_receive_from(net::buffer(receive_buffer), sender, read_loop);
};

read_loop(error_code{}, -1); // prime the async pump

// after 5s stop
std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
post(io, [&s] { s.cancel(); });

io.join();
```

At the end, we can report the statistics:

```
std::cout << "A total of " << received_packets << " were received from "
          << unique_senders.size() << " unique senders\n";
```

With a similated load in `bash`:

```
function client() { while read a; do echo "$a" > /dev/udp/localhost/1234 ; done < /etc/dictionaries-common/words; }

for a in {1..20}; do client& done; time wait
```

We get:

```
A total of 294808 were received from 28215 unique senders

real    0m5,007s
user    0m0,801s
sys     0m0,830s
```

[image]

This is obviously not optimized, the bottle neck here is likely the *many many* bash subshells being launched for the clients.

### Full Listing

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

namespace net = boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main ()
{
    net::thread_pool io(1); // single threaded
    udp::socket s{io, {{}, 1234}};

    std::set<udp::endpoint> unique_senders;
    size_t                  received_packets = 0;

    {
        std::array<char, 100> receive_buffer;
        udp::endpoint sender;

        std::function<void(error_code, size_t)> read_loop;
        read_loop = [&](error_code ec, size_t bytes) {
            if (bytes != size_t(-1)) {
                //std::cout << "read_loop (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
                if (ec)
                    return;

                received_packets += 1;
                unique_senders.insert(sender);
                //std::cout << "Received:" << bytes << " sender:" << sender << " recorded:" << received_packets << "\n";
                //std::cout << std::string_view(receive_buffer.data(), bytes) << "\n";
            }
            s.async_receive_from(net::buffer(receive_buffer), sender, read_loop);
        };

        read_loop(error_code{}, -1); // prime the async pump

        // after 5s stop
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
        post(io, [&s] { s.cancel(); });

        io.join();
    }

    std::cout << "A total of " << received_packets << " were received from "
              << unique_senders.size() << " unique senders\n";
}
```

Comment: May I put one additional question ? I am a beginner in boost. 
How is possible to read from all the clients for 100 ms and 900 ms to ignore the messages or do nothing, and after again read 100ms and 900 ms do nothing ?

Comment: Erm. Just code that. There are multiple approaches. [Here's one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e7bc84b35d9c706), with local demo: https://imgur.com/a/2dklVKa, if you posted that as a separate question I would also explain it

Comment: (fixed the screen recording in my last comment)

Comment: i will post new question and I let you know. Thank you for your support !

Comment: I know that udp is connectionless, but in case if I should receive from some ip address with different ports, is possible to use boost instead of poll() from linux , using only one thread ?

Comment: I don't see what the "but" comes from. Does this example help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014155/boost-asio-and-udp-poll-no-incoming-data/72015194#72015194

Comment: Oh lol. That's this answer. Then I truly don't get the comment. My answer already does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I wasn't clear with my previous comment. I have X ip address with different ports which are sending data. Now because they are sharing data on different ports, I need to 'listen' all of this ports. Using udp protocol.

Comment: Did you look at the answer example? It reports 28215 unique sending addresses. The way it tells them apart is by comparing the `sender` (inserting them into a `unique_senders` to get unique counts). Uncomment the `std::cout` lines to see what it actually contains. Unsurprisingly it contains the ip and port of the sending parties.

Comment: First thank you for your support ! Yes, I did. What i am trying to say is that you are sending everything to one port from "server" side.  For example if we have ip 127.0.0.1 with port : 1234 127.0.0.1 with port 1235, so from receiver side we should 'listen' ip 127.0.0.1 with port 1234 and 127.0.0.1 with port 1235.

Comment: In that case, add sockets for each port you actively bind. Here's a simple take (just copied all the things related to `read_loop` into a class, and done): https://imgur.com/a/MrnoL0N see **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/837eeed9557c37b6)**

Comment: Thank you @sehe ! I have one more question, but maybe will be more easier to reach you by e-mail or something similar ?

Comment: I prefer to keep things on this site. It helps you and me better, because many more people can help on SO

Comment: I have one bottleneck. According to last code what you shared with me : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/837eeed9557c37b6 , 
I tried to add the condition : record 100 ms of the data and after resume the sockets, go to process collected data. When is done, start again 100 ms to collect data from sockets and again process for 900 ms etc... 
The problem is that each listener now have its own current time. I am thinking how to have everything in one place, and when 100 ms is elapsed, notify all 'listeners' to resume using "stop() function provided by you".

Comment: I did something like that : https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df41c1490bd097ce

I just add timer in the main and one flag which will enforce to get out from read_loop. Is this okay approach ? 

Can you help me to integrate "each " lambda into the class ? 
When I am trying to make std::function<void ()> each; Seems is not okay, as parameter is pointer to member function. And is failing.

Comment: I post the same question in different thread. In case if you have time, please have a look. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72364304/boost-asio-timeout-approach

Comment: The whole point of the way I calculated time slices was to allow for synchronization to a clock, without time-drift, so here's the combination with 1 timer per listener but synchronized time slices: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc9a200951c76f72
If you are _sure_ you are remaining single threaded, you might consider using the same actual timer, at the cost of a lot more complexity.