# Boost Asio Timeout Approach

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, udp, boost-asio

[image]

I have situation where I need to collect data from more than 100 clients in 100 ms. After that time I need to process collected data. When process is done, need to restart step where I am collecting data from the clients and so on in the loop.

To collect the data I am using the current implementation :

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>

namespace net = boost::asio;
using net::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct listener {

    using Buffer = std::array<char, 100>; // receiver buffer
    udp::socket s;

    listener(net::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : s{ex, {{}, port}} {}

    void start() {
        read_loop(error_code{}, -1); // prime the async pump
    }

    void stop() {
        post(s.get_executor(), [this] { s.cancel(); });
    }

    void report() const {
        std::cout << s.local_endpoint() << ": A total of " << received_packets
                  << " were received from " << unique_senders.size()
                  << " unique senders\n";
    }

private:
    Buffer receive_buffer;
    udp::endpoint         sender;

    std::set<udp::endpoint> unique_senders;
    size_t                  received_packets = 0;


    void read_loop(error_code ec, size_t bytes) {
        if (bytes != size_t(-1)) {
            // std::cout << "read_loop (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
            if (ec)
                return;

            received_packets += 1;
            unique_senders.insert(sender);
             std::cout << "Received:" << bytes << " sender:" << sender << " recorded:"
             << received_packets << "\n";
             //std::cout <<
            // std::string_view(receive_buffer.data(), bytes) << "\n";
        }
        s.async_receive_from(net::buffer(receive_buffer), sender,
                             std::bind_front(&listener::read_loop, this));
    };
};

int main() {
    net::thread_pool io(1); // single threaded

    using Timer = net::steady_timer;
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    Timer timer_(io);
    std::list<listener> listeners;

    auto each = [&](auto mf) { for (auto& l : listeners) (l.*mf)(); };

    for (uint16_t port : {1234, 1235, 1236})
        listeners.emplace_back(io.get_executor(), port);

    each(&listener::start);

    TimePoint startTP = Clock::now();
    timer_.expires_at(startTP + 100ms); // collect data for 100 ms
    timer_.async_wait([&](auto &&){each(&listener::stop);});

    std::cout << "Done ! \n";
    each(&listener::report);
    

    io.join();
}
```

**Is it okay approach to stop collecting process ?**

```
TimePoint startTP = Clock::now();
timer_.expires_at(startTP + 100ms); // collect data for 100 ms
timer_.async_wait([&](auto &&){each(&listener::stop);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting this as basically asking how to combine

- the [time slice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014155/boost-asio-and-udp-poll-no-incoming-data/72015194?noredirect=1#comment127250571_72015194) I gave earlier,
- with [the multi-listener example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014155/boost-asio-and-udp-poll-no-incoming-data/72015194?noredirect=1#comment127696501_72015194)

This is also reflected in your comment [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014155/boost-asio-and-udp-poll-no-incoming-data/72015194?noredirect=1#comment127835948_72015194):

> I have one bottleneck. According to last code what you shared with me : [...] I tried to add the condition : record 100 ms of the data and after resume the sockets, go to process collected data. When is done, start again 100 ms to collect data from sockets and again process for 900 ms etc... The problem is that each listener now have its own current time. I am thinking how to have everything in one place, and when 100 ms is elapsed, notify all 'listeners' to resume using "stop() function provided by you".

It would seem much easier to use the same time-slice calculation I used in the first (single-listener) example.

The whole point of the way I calculated time slices was to allow for synchronization to a clock, without time-drift. The beauty of it is that it translates 1:1 on multi-listeners.

Here's the combination with 1 timer per listener but synchronized time slices, created in exactly the same way I created the multi-listener sample from the original answer code:

> [*(just copied all the things related to read_loop into a class, and done)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014155/boost-asio-and-udp-poll-no-incoming-data/72015194?noredirect=1#:%7E:text=(just%20copied%20all%20the%20things%20related%20to%20read_loop%20into%20a%20class%2C%20and%20done))

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc9a200951c76f72)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>

namespace net = boost::asio;
using net::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using Timer = net::steady_timer;
constexpr auto period      = 1s;
constexpr auto armed_slice = 100ms;

struct listener {
    udp::socket s;

    listener(Clock::time_point start, net::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port)
        : s{ex, {{}, port}}
        , start_{start} {}

    void start() {
        read_loop(event::init, error_code{}, -1); // prime the async pump
    }

    void stop() {
        post(s.get_executor(), [this] {
            stopped_ = true;
            s.cancel();
            timer.cancel();
        });
    }

    void report() const {
        std::cout << s.local_endpoint() << ": A total of " << received_packets
                  << " were received from " << unique_senders.size()
                  << " unique senders\n";
    }

  private:
    std::atomic_bool stopped_{false};
    enum class event { init, resume, receive };

    Clock::time_point const start_;
    Timer                   timer{s.get_executor()};
    std::array<char, 100>   receive_buffer;
    udp::endpoint           sender;

    std::set<udp::endpoint> unique_senders;
    size_t                  received_packets = 0;

    void read_loop(event ev, error_code ec, [[maybe_unused]] size_t bytes) {
        if (stopped_)
            return;
        auto const now    = Clock::now();
        auto const relnow = now - start_;
        switch (ev) {
        case event::receive:
            // std::cout << s.local_endpoint() << "receive (" << ec.message()
            //<< ")\n";
            if (ec)
                return;

            if ((relnow % period) > armed_slice) {
                // ignore this receive

                // wait for next slice
                auto next_slice = start_ + period * (relnow / period + 1);
                std::cout << s.local_endpoint() << " Waiting "
                          << (next_slice - now) / 1ms << "ms ("
                          << received_packets << " received)\n";
                timer.expires_at(next_slice);
                return timer.async_wait(std::bind(&listener::read_loop, this,
                                                  event::resume, _1, 0));
            } else {
                received_packets += 1;
                unique_senders.insert(sender);
                /*
                 *std::cout << s.local_endpoint() << " Received:" << bytes
                 *          << " sender:" << sender
                 *          << " recorded:" << received_packets << "\n";
                 *std::cout << std::string_view(receive_buffer.data(), bytes)
                 *          << "\n";
                 */
            }
            break;
        case event::resume:
            //std::cout << "resume (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
            if (ec)
                return;
            break;
        case event::init:
            //std::cout << s.local_endpoint() << " init " << (now - start_) / 1ms << "ms\n";
            break;
        };
        s.async_receive_from(
            net::buffer(receive_buffer), sender,
            std::bind_front(&listener::read_loop, this, event::receive));
    }
};

int main() {
    net::thread_pool io(1); // single threaded

    std::list<listener> listeners;

    auto each = [&](auto mf) { for (auto& l : listeners) (l.*mf)(); };

    auto const start = Clock::now();

    for (uint16_t port : {1234, 1235, 1236})
        listeners.emplace_back(start, io.get_executor(), port);

    each(&listener::start);

    // after 5s stop
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    each(&listener::stop);

    io.join();
    
    each(&listener::report);
}
```

Live Demo:

[image]

**EDIT** In case the output goes too fast to interpret:

```
0.0.0.0:1234 Waiting 899ms (1587 received)
0.0.0.0:1236 Waiting 899ms (1966 received)
0.0.0.0:1235 Waiting 899ms (1933 received)
0.0.0.0:1235 Waiting 899ms (4054 received)
0.0.0.0:1234 Waiting 899ms (3454 received)
0.0.0.0:1236 Waiting 899ms (4245 received)
0.0.0.0:1236 Waiting 899ms (6581 received)
0.0.0.0:1235 Waiting 899ms (6257 received)
0.0.0.0:1234 Waiting 899ms (5499 received)
0.0.0.0:1235 Waiting 899ms (8535 received)
0.0.0.0:1234 Waiting 899ms (7494 received)
0.0.0.0:1236 Waiting 899ms (8811 received)
0.0.0.0:1236 Waiting 899ms (11048 received)
0.0.0.0:1234 Waiting 899ms (9397 received)
0.0.0.0:1235 Waiting 899ms (10626 received)
0.0.0.0:1234: A total of 9402 were received from 7932 unique senders
0.0.0.0:1235: A total of 10630 were received from 8877 unique senders
0.0.0.0:1236: A total of 11053 were received from 9133 unique senders
```

If you are *sure* you are remaining single threaded, you might consider using the same actual timer, at the cost of significantly increasing complexity.

Comment: Hi @sehe. First, thank you for your response ! Really appreciate . I did similar code like yours and I observed that from my side the timer for each listener is not perfect synchronised. I added photo result in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by " at the cost of significantly increasing complexity " ? 

I am not so sure if i will stay into single threaded or I will switch to multithreaded , as I need to collect for each client around 2500  packets. Each packet size is around 1200 bytes. 

I am not so sure if one thread is enough to collect and storage the data in 100 ms.

Comment: I did small modification to see in multithreading : 
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a9e2fe911f01a6e 

I keep idea to use one socket but writing in multithreading mode. 

But I see that time is not synchronised.  Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: By "increased complexity" I mean that your code becomes way more complicated due to sharing timers between logical strands (think of them as async threads) and the need for manual switching on timer expiration. Unless you can prove that having a single timer improves anything for you, I would not do it.

Comment: Idea to have one Timepoint which is reference for each of the "listeners" from my pov is the good one. What i saw on my machine, when i run the code, the waiting time is different for each listener. Meantime I tried to create with the same idea in background, the  "multithreaded " writer. I shared code in my previous comment.

Is it the right approach? I would like to know your view as to know if I really understand.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating, and ironically not synchronizing operations on `listeners`. At least use a strand per listener, and then don't do all the "posting" cargo cult. Posting to a free thread-pool executor is not actually bringing any synchronization anyways. E.g. with this https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e143a0ed463689a2 I get https://imgur.com/a/t8DZ2Yx just fine

Comment: Still think that's overcomplicating. Probably all you need is to run the listeners on a single thread and maybe dispatch the "work" (apparently some writing to storage) to a thread-pool. Presumably you also want to have explicit queue-ing there to avoid running out of resources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245026/discussion-between-furch-radeon-and-sehe).

Comment: I thought about this approach. I mean to have specific thread pool which will collect and store data into the storage. As 1 Producer, the socket and X Consumers, Workers (threads).
Just thinking how can i dispatch the receiving data to thread pool, using current implementation which you provide.

Comment: May I ask you one more question ?

Comment: If I would like to run all the listeners manually when I want for 100 ms. Is it possible to do like that for now ? 
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e133ac5ea2b928ab

Comment: I would like to ask you one question about boost asio and thread pool. Is it possible to reach you or can I post the question here ?

Comment: @FurchRadeon I'm here. We can also [open a new chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248446/room-for-sehe-and-furch-radeon). Posting on SO is always a good option if (a) the question is a good fit (b) hasn't been answered before :)